# IEnumerable совместимость со старым кодом

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Интереса ради начал изучать внутреннее устройство `foreach`.

Наткнулся на такой паттерн, который создан, чтобы была совместимость из старого кода:

```
class Test : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerator()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {

    }
}
```

Так как мы реализуем `generic` интерфейс, то должны реализовать и методы из `IEnumerable`, так как `generic` интерфейс наследует его.

Как я понял, при написании обычного `foreach` в текущих версиях языка, будет вызван неявный метод (который первый), исходя из понятия утиной типизации.

Вопрос: почему в старых версиях языка (до `generic`'ов) будет вызван метод с явной реализацией?

Возможно, там такая реализация (с привидением к `non-generic` интерфейсу)?

```
IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)TestInstance).GetEnumerator();
...
```

Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задаёте вопрос о C# 1.x, поскольку начиная с версии 2.0 C# уже содержит обобщения.

Посмотрим на [спецификацию C# 1.0](https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/e/a9e229b9-fee5-4c3e-8476-917dee385062/CSharp%20Language%20Specification%20v1.0.doc). Нас интересует раздел 8.8.4 *The foreach statement*.
Согласно этому разделу, используется следующая последовательность проверок:

1. Если выражение, по которому происходит итерация, поддерживает *паттерн итерации* (то есть, содержит публичный метод `GetEnumerator`, возвращающий объект, обладающий методом `MoveNext` и свойством `Current`), то используется этот паттерн (даже если интерфейс `IEnumerable` тоже поддерживается).
2. В противном случае, если поддерживается интерфейс `IEnumerable`, то он  используется.
3. В противном случае происходит ошибка компиляции.

В вашем случае, когда метод `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` объявлен через явную имплементацию интерфейса, первое условие не выполняется: метод `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` не публичный. (А метода `public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerator()` вовсе нет, раз наша версия языка не поддерживает обобщения.) Поэтому работает второе условие.

---

Кстати, [в современных версиях языка](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#the-foreach-statement) просто перед второй проверкой выполняется дополнительная проверка на обобщённый `IEnumerable<T>`. Но на первом месте в любом случае «утиная» проверка.

Comment: То есть, если мы данный код попробуем использовать в C# 1.0, то публичный метод просто будет игнорироваться (не существовать для данной версии языка)?

Comment: @khirnick: Он просто не скомпилируется. C# 1.0 вообще не знает, как понимать текст `IEnumerable<T>`, что это за знаки «больше» и «меньше».

Comment: тогда такой вопрос: как работает эта совместимость? Если данный код не скомпилируется, то смысл дополнительной реализации в виде поддержки non-generic?

Comment: я понял весь технический смысл. Но я не понял смысл такой реализации в современных реалиях

Comment: @khirnick: Смысл поддержки non-generic в том, чтобы старые коллекции, которые реализовали `IEnumerable`, но не `IEnumerable<T>`, продолжали работать с `foreach`.

Comment: @khirnick: Смысл чего именно вам неясен? Утиная типизация нужна для того, чтобы избежать упаковки. Поддержка `IEnumerable` нужна для обратной совместимости. Поддержка `IEnumerable<T>` нужна, хм, потому что как же без неё?

Comment: понял, разобрался. Вопрос: реализация явного метода (ienumerator ienumerable.GetEnumerator) в новых версиях сделана "для галочки"? То есть, если мы пишем новую библиотеку на современных версиях языка, то реализация этого метода сделана "для галочки"?

Comment: Именно потому, что интерфейс Ienumerable<T> этого требует

Comment: Я правильно понял?

Comment: @khirnick: Эээ... Не понял вопроса. Почему «для галочки»?

Comment: Если мы реализуем IEnumerable<t>, то из здравого смысла, мы предполагаем, что будем пользоваться generic возможностями. Следовательно, зачем нам non generic? Но реализуя IEnumerable<T>, мы обязаны реализовать обычный (non generic) IEnunerable... То есть, исходя из логики, мы реализуем его потому что "НАДО" . Так я понял?

Comment: @khirnick: А, понял. Смотрите. Если мы пишем на C#, то нам достаточно generic-варианта. Но мы можем ведь и пользоваться другим языком, основанным на CLR, например, IronPython или какой-нибудь реализацией Javascript. А в ней generic-ов нет. Так вот, чтобы они могли итерировать по коллекции, нужна и поддержка `IEnumerable`.

Comment: да, это я имел в виду (про достаточность generic-ов). Хм. Если мы будем использовать IronPython, то окружение знает, что IronPython не поддерживает generic'и и будет вызван НУЖНЫЙ метод, возвращающий объект перечислителя?

Comment: @khirnick: Наоборот, это IronPython, имея объект, опрашивает интерфейс `IEnumerable`, и проводит по нему перечисление. И если у вас поддерживается `IEnumerable<T>`, то поддерживается и `IEnumerable`, а значит, перечисление сработает.

Comment: я вас понял! Спасибо за объяснение! Во многих вопросах очень сильно помогли мне!

Comment: @khirnick: Пожалуйста! Рад, если обсуждение оказалось полезным!